# Как правильно подключить расширения gdx-freetype

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Предполагаю,что я не правильно делаю.Сильно не пинайте
после запуска падает с ошибками:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'java.lang.String com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator$FreeTypeFontParameter.characters' on a null object reference
                                                                     at upwardteam.pavel.game.Drop.create(Drop.java:25)
```

Ругается на :

```
   parameter.characters = FONT_CHARS;
```

Все делаю по этой инструкции:
https://new.vk.com/topic-44557600_29206090
       Главный класс:

```
 public class Drop extends Game {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;
    final String FONT_PATH = "comic-sans-ms.ttf";
    final String FONT_CHARS
            = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.;:,{}\"´`'<>";
    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
     parameter.characters = FONT_CHARS;
        generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(FONT_PATH));
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));



    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        generator.dispose();
    }
}
```

Игровой класс:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

final Drop game;
OrthographicCamera camera;
Texture dropImage;
Texture bucketImage;
Sound dropSound;
Music rainMusic;
Rectangle bucket;
Vector3 touchPos;
Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
long lastDropTime;
int dropsGatchered;




public GameScreen (final Drop gam) {
    this.game = gam;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

    touchPos = new Vector3();

    dropImage = new Texture("droplet.png");
    bucketImage = new Texture("bucket.png");

    dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("waterdrop.wav"));
    rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("undertreeinrain.mp3"));

    rainMusic.setLooping(true);
    rainMusic.play();

    bucket = new Rectangle();
    bucket.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2;
    bucket.y = 20;
    bucket.width = 64;
    bucket.height = 64;


    raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnRaindrop();

}

private void spawnRaindrop(){
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800-64);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 64;
    raindrop.height = 64;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void render (float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    game.parameter.size = 15;
    game.parameter.color = Color.BLACK;
    camera.update();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Drops Collected: " + dropsGatchered, 15, 480);
    game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
    for (Rectangle raindrop: raindrops){
        game.batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
    }
    game.batch.end();

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPos);
        bucket.x = (int) (touchPos.x -64 / 2);
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    if (bucket.x < 0) bucket.x = 0;
    if (bucket.x > 800 - 64) bucket.x = 800 - 64;

    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRaindrop();

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
        raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0) iter.remove();
        if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)){
            dropsGatchered++;
            dropSound.play();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    dropImage.dispose();
    bucketImage.dispose();
    dropSound.dispose();
    rainMusic.dispose();
}

@Override
public void show() {
    rainMusic.play();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Добавь эту строку в `create()`

```
parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
```

Разумеется перед

```
parameter.characters = FONT_CHARS;
```